# Sipek sdk turn off echo cancellation

Tags: sdk, echo, sip, voip

During a call, if I am not actively speaking into the microphone, it appears as if there are no audio packets being sent.  This is causing problems because I am tring to mix audio at the server level.  It appears to be some kind of echo cancellation in the pjsip stack.  Does anybody know if there is a way to shut this off?

I have tested with Zoiper and I have isolated the problem to this sdk.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually not because of AEC. You should look for something called "VAD" (Voice Activity Detection). If you find it try to change its setting or disable it.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't sure what it was called but after doing some research on it, I was able to disable it.

Comment: @Jim , I couldn't find your email address I would really appreciated if you could send me your email address my email address farzad.salimijazi@gmail.com, thanks in advance